# Check datatable columns against list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a list of values. (Currently on a piece of paper, but this could be List or whatever you suggest).

As follows:

```
Name,
Type,
Phone,
Contract, 
Remark
```

Now I have a datatable which is imported from a file. I need to check if datatable contains the same columns from my list. (So my datatable should have 5 columns `Name, Type, Phone, Contract, Remark).` I'd like to check regardless of position, but if persisting position of columns is faster, I would prefer faster solution. 
i know you can something like

```
Foreach column in datatable 
if columnname exist in list and ListSize ==Datatable.Columns.Count then 
    continue 
else 
    return false`.
```

but I'd like a faster solution.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me.  It's a pretty simple check if that's all you need.  Any particular reason why you need a "faster solution"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way to lookup a value is to use a hash-table. In this case I would suggest a `HashSet<T>`

```
var requiredColumns = new HashSet<string>
    { "Name", "Type", "Phone", "Contract", "Remark" };
if (datatable.Columns.Count != requiredColumns.Count) {
    Console.WriteLine("Number of columns does not match!");
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++) {
        string colname = datatable.Columns[i].Name;
        if (!requiredColumns.Contains(colname)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown column [{0}]", colname);
        }
    }  
}
```